# Occasionally Getting Connector Error Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: php, quickbooks

Occasionally 1 of our users is getting "Unable to connect to the remote server" and "The operation has timed out" errors when syncing their QB data via Intuit's web connector to our SOAP service. This is particularly problematic when it occurs for ReceiveResponseXML as we do not get the notification that something was added or updated in QB.

We cannot finds anything in our server, apache, or PHP logs that show the server rejecting the requests. Also we have dozens of customers using our software and this is the only user with this issue.

Any ideas what might be causing this. I'm not even sure if it is a server issue or a network issue with our user. Thanks in advance!

Here is a portion of the log for the "The operation has timed out" error.

```
20230510.19:07:10 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""

20230510.19:07:10 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Received from receiveResponseXML() following parameters:

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : more="1">

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : There are more requests to process.

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Asking application to send request no. 3

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : *** Calling sendRequestXML() with following parameters:

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : wcTicket="{BC7DFDDF-F817-CA1A-F066-B6F2009F6F35}"

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : HCPResponseXML=

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : 

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : cfn="PATH.qbw"

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbNationality="US"

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMajorVers="16"

20230510.19:07:11 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMinorVers="0"

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Received from sendRequestXML() following parameter:

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : strRequestXML =

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -

 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="12.0"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError"><ReceivePaymentAddRq><ReceivePaymentAdd><CustomerRef><ListID>57E0000-1297107795</ListID></CustomerRef><ARAccountRef><FullName>Accts Rec - Trade</FullName></ARAccountRef><TxnDate>2023-05-10</TxnDate><RefNumber></RefNumber><TotalAmount>117.15</TotalAmount><Memo></Memo><AppliedToTxnAdd><TxnID>63EAD7-1682424060</TxnID><PaymentAmount>117.15</PaymentAmount></AppliedToTxnAdd></ReceivePaymentAdd></ReceivePaymentAddRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>

 

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #3

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from application: size (bytes) = 539

20230510.19:07:12 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to QuickBooks.

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Response received from QuickBooks: size (bytes) = 1118

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending response back to application.

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : *** Calling receiveResponseXML() with following parameters:

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : wcTicket="{BC7DFDDF-F817-CA1A-F066-B6F2009F6F35}"

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : response =

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : XML dump follows: -

 

<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<QBXML>

<QBXMLMsgsRs>

<ReceivePaymentAddRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

<ReceivePaymentRet>

<TxnID>646685-1683745633</TxnID>

<TimeCreated>2023-05-10T15:07:13-05:00</TimeCreated>

<TimeModified>2023-05-10T15:07:13-05:00</TimeModified>

<EditSequence>1683745633</EditSequence>

<TxnNumber>806248</TxnNumber>

<CustomerRef>

<ListID>57E0000-1297107795</ListID>

<FullName>Customer Name</FullName>

</CustomerRef>

<ARAccountRef>

<ListID>3B0000-1057131910</ListID>

<FullName>Accts Rec - Trade</FullName>

</ARAccountRef>

<TxnDate>2023-05-10</TxnDate>

<TotalAmount>117.15</TotalAmount>

<DepositToAccountRef>

<ListID>80000-1056145226</ListID>

<FullName>Undeposited Funds</FullName>

</DepositToAccountRef>

<UnusedPayment>0.00</UnusedPayment>

<UnusedCredits>0.00</UnusedCredits>

<AppliedToTxnRet>

<TxnID>63EAD7-1682424060</TxnID>

<TxnType>Invoice</TxnType>

<TxnDate>2023-04-25</TxnDate>

<RefNumber>127115</RefNumber>

<BalanceRemaining>0.00</BalanceRemaining>

<Amount>117.15</Amount>

</AppliedToTxnRet>

</ReceivePaymentRet>

</ReceivePaymentAddRs>

</QBXMLMsgsRs>

</QBXML>

 

 

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""

20230510.19:07:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""

20230510.19:09:13 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed

Error message: The operation has timed out

More info:

StackTrace =  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)

  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)

  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

  at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)

  at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)

  at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket, String response, String hresult, String message)

  at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket, String response, String hresult, String message, Boolean& success, Boolean& timeout)

Source = System.Web.Services
```

Here is the log for "Unable to connect to remote server" error.

```
20230510.14:31:15 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.

20230510.14:31:15 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #3

20230510.14:31:15 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from application: size (bytes) = 1831

20230510.14:31:15 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to QuickBooks.

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Response received from QuickBooks: size (bytes) = 3534

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending response back to application.

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : *** Calling receiveResponseXML() with following parameters:

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : wcTicket="{BC7DFDDF-F817-CA1A-F066-B6F2009F6F35}"

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : response =

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : XML dump follows: -

 

<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<QBXML>

<QBXMLMsgsRs>

<InvoiceAddRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">

<InvoiceRet>

<TxnID>6461DB-1683729076</TxnID>

<TimeCreated>2023-05-10T10:31:16-05:00</TimeCreated>

<TimeModified>2023-05-10T10:31:16-05:00</TimeModified>

<EditSequence>1683729076</EditSequence>

<TxnNumber>806101</TxnNumber>

<CustomerRef>

<ListID>80000735-1403623756</ListID>

<FullName>Customer Name</FullName>

</CustomerRef>

<ARAccountRef>

<ListID>3B0000-1057131910</ListID>

<FullName>Accts Rec - Trade</FullName>

</ARAccountRef>

<TemplateRef>

<ListID>10000-1056145149</ListID>

<FullName>Intuit Product Invoice</FullName>

</TemplateRef>

<TxnDate>2023-05-10</TxnDate>

<RefNumber>128528</RefNumber>

<BillAddress>

<Addr1>Addr1</Addr1>

<City>City</City>

<State>OH</State>

<PostalCode>00000</PostalCode>

<Country>USA</Country>

</BillAddress>

<BillAddressBlock>

<Addr1>Addr1</Addr1>

<Addr2>Addr2</Addr2>

<Addr3>US</Addr3>

</BillAddressBlock>

<ShipAddress>

<Addr1>Addr1</Addr1>

<City>City</City>

<State>OH</State>

<PostalCode>00000</PostalCode>

<Country>USA</Country>

</ShipAddress>

<ShipAddressBlock>

<Addr1>Addr1</Addr1>

<Addr2>Addr2</Addr2>

<Addr3>US</Addr3>

</ShipAddressBlock>

<IsPending>false</IsPending>

<IsFinanceCharge>false</IsFinanceCharge>

<DueDate>2023-05-10</DueDate>

<ShipDate>2023-05-10</ShipDate>

<Subtotal>183.61</Subtotal>

<SalesTaxPercentage>0.00</SalesTaxPercentage>

<SalesTaxTotal>0.00</SalesTaxTotal>

<AppliedAmount>0.00</AppliedAmount>

<BalanceRemaining>183.61</BalanceRemaining>

<IsPaid>false</IsPaid>

<IsToBePrinted>false</IsToBePrinted>

<IsToBeEmailed>false</IsToBeEmailed>

<InvoiceLineRet>

<TxnLineID>6461DD-1683729076</TxnLineID>

<ItemRef>

<ListID>8000007D-1541172899</ListID>

<FullName>Item Name</FullName>

</ItemRef>

<Desc>Desc</Desc>

<Quantity>1</Quantity>

<Rate>0.00</Rate>

<Amount>0.00</Amount>

<SalesTaxCodeRef>

<ListID>20000-1056145151</ListID>

<FullName>Non</FullName>

</SalesTaxCodeRef>

</InvoiceLineRet>

<InvoiceLineRet>

<TxnLineID>6461DE-1683729076</TxnLineID>

<ItemRef>

<ListID>800000C6-1541172934</ListID>

<FullName>Item Name</FullName>

</ItemRef>

<Desc>Brux-C</Desc>

<Quantity>1</Quantity>

<Rate>172</Rate>

<Amount>172.00</Amount>

<SalesTaxCodeRef>

<ListID>20000-1056145151</ListID>

<FullName>Non</FullName>

</SalesTaxCodeRef>

</InvoiceLineRet>

<InvoiceLineRet>

<TxnLineID>6461DF-1683729076</TxnLineID>

<ItemRef>

<ListID>8000007C-1541172839</ListID>

<FullName>Line Item</FullName>

</ItemRef>

<Desc>Teeth</Desc>

<Quantity>1</Quantity>

<Rate>0.00</Rate>

<Amount>0.00</Amount>

<SalesTaxCodeRef>

<ListID>20000-1056145151</ListID>

<FullName>Non</FullName>

</SalesTaxCodeRef>

</InvoiceLineRet>

<InvoiceLineRet>

<TxnLineID>6461E0-1683729076</TxnLineID>

<ItemRef>

<ListID>8000007C-1541172839</ListID>

<FullName>Line Item</FullName>

</ItemRef>

<Desc>Shade</Desc>

<Quantity>1</Quantity>

<Rate>0.00</Rate>

<Amount>0.00</Amount>

<SalesTaxCodeRef>

<ListID>20000-1056145151</ListID>

<FullName>Non</FullName>

</SalesTaxCodeRef>

</InvoiceLineRet>

<InvoiceLineRet>

<TxnLineID>6461E1-1683729076</TxnLineID>

<ItemRef>

<ListID>80000383-1541180042</ListID>

<FullName>Item Name</FullName>

</ItemRef>

<Desc>Desc</Desc>

<Quantity>1</Quantity>

<Rate>11.61</Rate>

<Amount>11.61</Amount>

<SalesTaxCodeRef>

<ListID>20000-1056145151</ListID>

<FullName>Non</FullName>

</SalesTaxCodeRef>

</InvoiceLineRet>

</InvoiceRet>

</InvoiceAddRs>

</QBXMLMsgsRs>

</QBXML>

 

 

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""

20230510.14:31:16 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Received from receiveResponseXML() following parameters:

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : more="2">

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : There are more requests to process.

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Asking application to send request no. 4

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : *** Calling sendRequestXML() with following parameters:

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : wcTicket="{BC7DFDDF-F817-CA1A-F066-B6F2009F6F35}"

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : HCPResponseXML=

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : 

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : cfn="PATH.qbw"

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbNationality="US"

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMajorVers="16"

20230510.14:31:17 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : qbXMLMinorVers="0"

20230510.14:32:00 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : QBWC1041: SendRequestXML failed.

Error message: Unable to connect to the remote server

More info:

StackTrace =  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)

  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

  at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.sendRequestXML(String ticket, String strHCPResponse, String strCompanyFileName, String qbXMLCountry, Int32 qbXMLMajorVers, Int32 qbXMLMinorVers)

  at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.sendRequestXML(String ticket, String strHCPResponse, String strCompanyFileName, String qbXMLCountry, Int32 qbXMLMajorVers, Int32 qbXMLMinorVers)

  at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.sendRequestXML(String wcTicket, String HCPResponseXML, String cfn, String qbNationality, Int32 qbXMLMajorVers, Int32 qbXMLMinorVers)

  at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_sendRequestXML(Int32 x, String wcTicket, String HCPResponseXML, String cfn, String qbNationality, Int32 qbXMLMajorVers, Int32 qbXMLMinorVers, Boolean& timeout)

Source = System
```